# Send attached file with Mailgun using python

Tags: python, python-requests, multipartform-data, email-attachments, mailgun

I'm trying to send an email with an attached file with the Mailgun API using requests.post.

In their documentation they alert that **you must use** multipart/form-data encoding when sending attachments, I'm trying this:

```
import requests
MAILGUN_URL = 'https://api.mailgun.net/v3/sandbox4f...'
MAILGUN_KEY = 'key-f16f497...'


def mailgun(file_url):
    """Send an email using MailGun"""

    f = open(file_url, 'rb')

    r = requests.post(
        MAILGUN_URL,
        auth=("api", MAILGUN_KEY),
        data={
            "subject": "My subject",
            "from": "my_email@gmail.com",
            "to": "to_you@gmail.com",
            "text": "The text",
            "html": "The<br>html",
            "attachment": f
        },
        headers={'Content-type': 'multipart/form-data;'},
    )

    f.close()

    return r


mailgun("/tmp/my-file.xlsx")
```

I've defined the header to be sure that the content type is **multipart/form-data**, but when I run the code, I get a 400 status with reason: Bad Request

What's wrong? **I need be sure that i'm using multipart/form-data** and I'm using correctly the **attachment** parameter

Comment: I would advise to go over this [documentation](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html) before doing anything on the web. If you know the error codes you immediately know where to look for the bugs. In this case: some parameter is missing or is warded incorrectly

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You need to use the `files` keyword argument. [Here](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/#post-a-multipart-encoded-file) is the documentation in requests.

And an example from the Mailgun documentation:

```
def send_complex_message():
    return requests.post(
        "https://api.mailgun.net/v3/YOUR_DOMAIN_NAME/messages",
        auth=("api", "YOUR_API_KEY"),
        files=[("attachment", open("files/test.jpg")),
               ("attachment", open("files/test.txt"))],
        data={"from": "Excited User <YOU@YOUR_DOMAIN_NAME>",
              "to": "foo@example.com",
              "cc": "baz@example.com",
              "bcc": "bar@example.com",
              "subject": "Hello",
              "text": "Testing some Mailgun awesomness!",
              "html": "<html>HTML version of the body</html>"})
```

So modify your POST to:

```
r = requests.post(
    MAILGUN_URL,
    auth=("api", MAILGUN_KEY),
    files = [("attachment", f)],
    data={
        "subject": "My subject",
        "from": "my_email@gmail.com",
        "to": "to_you@gmail.com",
        "text": "The text",
        "html": "The<br>html"
    },
    headers={'Content-type': 'multipart/form-data;'},
)
```

This should work fine for you.

---

Quick note about the `headers` arg:

Specifying `headers` in a request is perfectly fine with both `requests` and Mailgun. In fact, headers are set in the [first example in Mailgun's documentation](https://documentation.mailgun.com/en/latest/api-events.html?highlight=headers#viewing-stored-messages).

That said, there are some caveats that you should be aware if if you choose to send headers. From `requests` [documentation](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user/quickstart/?highlight=headers#custom-headers) (emphasis mine):

> Note: Custom headers are given less precedence than more specific sources of information. For instance:
>
> Authorization headers set with headers= will be overridden if credentials are specified in .netrc, which in turn will be overridden by the auth= parameter. Requests will search for the netrc file at ~/.netrc, ~/_netrc, or at the path specified by the NETRC environment variable.
>
> Authorization headers will be removed if you get redirected off-host.
>
> Proxy-Authorization headers will be overridden by proxy credentials provided in the URL.
>
> Content-Length headers will be overridden when we can determine the length of the content.
>
> Furthermore, **Requests does not change its behavior at all based on which custom headers are specified. The headers are simply passed on into the final request.**

Comment: Works for me but only if I don't specify the `headers` arg. Seems this is handled automatically anyway.